# CSS to add class to first img in div when all text and images are wrapped in <p> tags

Tags: css, wordpress

We have a `Wordpress` site and the way we've added the images to all of the posts has left the posts looking like this:

```
<div class="entry-content">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <p>More Text</p>
  <p><img src="http://something.com"></p> <-- This is the img I'm trying to get</p>
  <p><img src="http://somethingelse.com"></p>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use nth-of-type(1) to apply a class to that first image?

Comment: You'll probably need JavaScript for this.

Comment: You could forgo the class and use CSS3. example in a moment.

Comment: Solved it. Wordpress adds the <p> tag to any image automatically. The solution is to modify your functions.php file to  [strip tags from img](http://www.dino-digital.com/news/wordpress/unwrap-images-from-paragraph-tags/), then you can use nth-of-type to get the first img in the post.

Comment: Glad to see you figured it out. If the problem is solved, feel free to select an accepted answer from the 5 you were provided :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--EDITED--**
@ Original Poster:
You can target which one does what simply by changing the values in the CSS. Compare this with the below link: http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/xgL69/3/

**And if you can get rid of the `<p>` tags, use `first-child`:
http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/xgL69/4/**

## Here's a quick mock up for ya:

#### http://jsfiddle.net/SinisterSystems/xgL69/2/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="cont">
    <p><img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1.jpg" /></p>
    <p><img src="http://www.extremetech.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/image-1.jpg" /></p>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cont p:nth-of-type(1) img:nth-of-type(1) {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
}
```

Comment: -1 images are wrapped by a paragraph in the question

Comment: Your edit wont work if a text paragraph comes before the image

Comment: @NicholasHazel  No worries

Comment: @ryanS And the page won't work if they add 6 divs either. We can go in circles all day. The principle is proven, just change your vals in the CSS around.

Comment: If they wanted to edit the css with each post wouldnt it make more sense to just add a class to the image?

Comment: If it's possible to add a class to the first image in a post I think that would work just fine.

Comment: Yes, and the only way to do that is with a script, and it appears he doesn't want to use javascript, as he didn't tag it.

Comment: @NicholasHazel I was hoping not to use JS but if I have to I can.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are wrapping them in <p>? Cause I could make this super easy.

Comment: @NicholasHazel I actually have no idea why they're wrapped in <p> tags. I think it was an old plug in we were using for mass image uploading.

Comment: Hmm, so removing the `p` tag isn't an option? Because that dramatically makes this problem much easier.

Comment: @NicholasHazel I just commented on my original post that I found some code to add to the functions.php file to remove the p tag from all images. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The key, as you mentioned, was [getting rid of the p tags](http://www.dino-digital.com/news/wordpress/unwrap-images-from-paragraph-tags/).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p:nth-of-type(1) img
```

or if there's more than one img

```
p:nth-of-type(1) img:nth-of-type(1)
```

Comment: Hm... Didn't work for me. Seemed to not apply to any p tags or images.

Comment: Yeah, I am fiddling with it.  The problem is that what I've posted will only work if the first paragraph is the one with an image.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work:

```
div.entry-content p:nth-last-child(2) img {
    border:4px solid #faa;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7UNX2/2/)**

Comment: In your example, yes, but what happens if there aren't exactly 2 paragraphs of text, then an image?

Comment: If you need to dynamically change based on different layouts and whatnot, then JS is required unless you want to build 10 million IDs and configurations. Otherwise, if all of your pages will have the same structure, you can just change the values in the CSS. View my post for comparison.

Comment: @MattBlum - Updated. This will select the second to last paragraph's image.

Comment: @j08691 Thanks man. The answer was in stripping the p tags to be able to use nth-of-type. Made it so much easier.

Answer (score -1):

`p img:first { block:display; }`

To add a class with jquery:

`$('p img:first').addClass('yourClass');`

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6qd24/

Sorry, had `first-of-type` incorrectly.

Comment: Wasnt me but this would target the first image in every paragraph

Comment: That's what I had and it's exactly what it did. Every image took the style instead of just the first one.

Comment: Not sure. Could be perhaps the user tagged CSS, and if there is an easy CSS solution I don't imagine using a script is the best way to go about it.

Comment: Well if css CAN do it it SHOULD do it, but if you're dead set on a class, you can use javascript (or jquery). That's why I added both. *downvoters are trolls that live in their mothers basement*